# Array indexing with boolean array

Tags: modelica

Given a Real array (e.g. `myArray`) and a Boolean array (e.g. `myMask`), I'd like to have:

- if `myMask[i] == true` then `myArray[i] = myValueTrue`
- if `myMask[i] == false` then `myArray[i] = myValueFalse`

This **does** work

```
model BooleanIndexing
  parameter Boolean myMask[3] = {false, true, true};
  parameter Boolean myMask_negated[3] = {true, false, false};
  Real myArray[3];
  parameter Real myValueTrue = 3.0;
  parameter Real myValueFalse = 5.0;
equation
  myArray[Modelica.Math.BooleanVectors.index(myMask)] = fill(myValueTrue, Modelica.Math.BooleanVectors.countTrue(myMask));
  myArray[Modelica.Math.BooleanVectors.index(myMask_negated)] = fill(myValueFalse, Modelica.Math.BooleanVectors.countTrue(myMask_negated));
end BooleanIndexing;
```

but this **does not**

```
model BooleanIndexing
  parameter Boolean myMask[3] = {false, true, true};
  parameter Boolean myMask_negated[3] = not myMask;
  Real myArray[3];
  parameter Real myValueTrue = 3.0;
  parameter Real myValueFalse = 5.0;
equation
  myArray[Modelica.Math.BooleanVectors.index(myMask)] = fill(myValueTrue, Modelica.Math.BooleanVectors.countTrue(myMask));
  myArray[Modelica.Math.BooleanVectors.index(myMask_negated)] = fill(myValueFalse, Modelica.Math.BooleanVectors.countTrue(myMask_negated));
end BooleanIndexing;
```

The only difference is how I initialized `myMask_negated`.

The errors are, in OpenModelica:

```
[BooleanIndexing: 9:3-9:139]: Illegal subscript Modelica.Math.BooleanVectors.index({myMask_negated[1], myMask_negated[2], myMask_negated[3]}) for dimensions 3 in component myArray[Modelica.Math.BooleanVectors.index(myMask_negated)].

[BooleanIndexing: 9:3-9:139]: Variable myArray[Modelica.Math.BooleanVectors.index(myMask_negated)] not found in scope BooleanIndexing.

Error occurred while flattening model BooleanIndexing
```

and in Dymola2018

```
Translation of BooleanIndexing:

Failed to expand myArray[Modelica.Math.BooleanVectors.index(myMask)].

Errors or failure to expand the equation:
myArray[Modelica.Math.BooleanVectors.index(myMask)] = fill(myValueTrue, Modelica.Math.BooleanVectors.countTrue(myMask));
Found in class BooleanIndexing, C:/workspace/modelica_vehicle/modelica_test/BooleanIndexing.mo at line 8.

Errors or failure to expand vector or matrix expressions.

Translation aborted.
```

Direct boolean indexing `myArray[myMask]` seems not to be the solution here.
I cannot see why they are failing and if there are any more elegant solutions.

Comment: I'm not having the same issue in Dymola 2018 when simulating the *not* working example. There were some issues related to the compiler (with Visual Studio Build Essentials 2017), but your error would actually happen before that step I think. Nevertheless: I have used Dymola 2018 with Visual Studio 2015 and this seems to work...

Comment: Some additional information to the above comment: It worked due to the evaluate flag set to true. For this example this relates to: Advanced.EvaluateAlsoTop = true;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your versions do not guarantee that the correct number of equations are generated.
`myValueTrue` and `myValueTrue_negated` are both parameters, so the user can change the values of the vectors to something which is not complementary.

Hence, I would have recommended to set

```
final parameter Boolean myMask_negated[3] = not myMask;
```

but this also does not work, neither in Open Modelica nor in Dymola.

So instead, I recommend to delete `myMask_negated` and use for loops instead.
Either with two seperate ones:

```
model BooleanIndexing
  parameter Boolean myMask[3] = {false, true, true};
  Real myArray[3];
  parameter Real myValueTrue = 3.0;
  parameter Real myValueFalse = 5.0;
equation 
  for i in Modelica.Math.BooleanVectors.index(myMask) loop
    myArray[i] = myValueTrue;
  end for;

  for i in Modelica.Math.BooleanVectors.index(not myMask) loop
    myArray[i] = myValueFalse;
  end for;

end BooleanIndexing;
```

or with a single for loop using an array constructor, as shown here:

```
model BooleanIndexing2
  parameter Boolean myMask[3] = {false, true, true};
  Real myArray[3];
  parameter Real myValueTrue = 3.0;
  parameter Real myValueFalse = 5.0;
equation 

  myArray = {if value then myValueTrue else myValueFalse for value in myMask};

end BooleanIndexing2;
```